# Given an id, can you get the "index" of that items id in a sorted query

Tags: sql, sqlite

**EDIT:
I am using android versions that don't have a sqlite version > 2.35.  I cannot use ROW_NUMBER.**

Given the following table:

```
id, date(long)
1, 100
2, 25
3, 5
4, 50
```

If I query for items sorted:

select * from items order by date:

```
id, date
3, 5
2, 25
4, 50
1, 100
```

If I have id 4, can I query to get the index in the sorted list, in this case index *"3"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT rn
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) rn 
  FROM items
)
WHERE id = 4;
```

An alternative, for versions of SQLite prior to 3.25.0+ which don't support window functions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 rn
FROM items
WHERE date > (SELECT date FROM items WHERE id = 4);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=403b590307ba170f3d08d6f0c45bbe76).

Comment: Sorry, with my version of android and sqlite i cannot use row_number

Comment: @lostintranslation check my 2nd query.

Comment: awesome thank you and sorry for my confusion on the original question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the location of the row according to a custom ordering. The query can look like:

```
select rn
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over(order by date) as rn from t
) x
where id = 4
```

Comment: Sorry, with my version of android and sqlite i cannot use row_number